# Attempt to prove Fermat's Last Theorem n = 3.

Tags: number-theory

My previous attempt at proof did not work as I thought and so I decided to try again. Please bear in mind that this is **not a duplicate** of my old proof. If you look at the other one you will see that this examines the parity of the equation, something the previous attempt does not do. This time I have based my attempt on induction rather than algebra.

To begin with, I examined the equation:
$$ A^3 + B^3 = C^3$$
Where $A$, $B$, $C$ $\in \Bbb Z$ and $A$, $B$, $C > 0$. We can also assume that $A, B, C$ are the lowest solutions. Therefore, $A^3, B^3, C^3$ are co-prime.

Examining this, we should be able to draw conclusions on each term's parity.
In this form, we could have:
$$(1)EVEN + ODD = ODD$$
$$(2)ODD + ODD = EVEN$$
$$(3)EVEN + EVEN = EVEN$$

However, equation $3$ is not possible as we know that $A^3, B^3, C^3$ are the lowest solutions possible and are co-prime. Therefore, we are left only with $1$ and $2$.

My previous attempted solution involved rewriting the equation in terms of $A^3$:
$$A^3 + xA^3 = C^3$$
Here $x$ is either an integer, irrational or fraction.
If it is an integer we get:
$$(1+x)A^3 = C^3$$
Since $x \in \Bbb Z$, $x+1 \in \Bbb Z$. Therefore, $\sqrt[3]{x+1} \in \Bbb Z$ and $\sqrt[3]{x} \in \Bbb Z$.
The only possible integer solution to this is $x = 0$. However, this would mean that $B^3 = 0$. 
Therefore, $x$ is irrational or a fraction.
If $x$ is irrational, $B^3$ will be irrational.

Therefore, $x$ is a fraction.

We can now represent this in the equation:
$$A^3 + \frac{p^3}{q^3}A^3 = C^3$$
Where $p,q \in \Bbb Z$. The reason the fraction can be represented as such is because that is the ratio of $A^3$ to $B^3$. Even if $p^3$ and $q^3$ did share factors they could be simplified to still be cubes. (For example, $\frac{64}{8} = 8$.)

Simplifying this further we get:
$$(qA)^3 + (pA)^3 = (qC)^3$$

We shall begin by analysing $qA$. We know from earlier that this is either odd or even. If we assume it is even, then either:
$$\frac{A}{2} \in \Bbb Z , \frac{q}{2} \notin \Bbb Z$$
or $$\frac{A}{2} \notin \Bbb Z , \frac{q}{2} \in \Bbb Z$$ 
or $$\frac{A}{2} \in \Bbb Z , \frac{q}{2} \in \Bbb Z$$

Analysing $pA$, we can see from before that $pA$ must be odd. Therefore:
$$\frac{A}{2} \notin \Bbb Z , \frac{p}{2} \notin \Bbb Z$$
This means we can compare this with the other possible parities of $A$ to give:

$$\frac{A}{2} \notin \Bbb Z$$
$$\frac{p}{2} \notin \Bbb Z$$
$$\frac{q}{2} \in \Bbb Z$$

Substituting this all into our equation gives us:
$$(EVEN)^3 + (ODD)^3 = (EVEN)^3$$
$$EVEN + ODD = EVEN$$

This clearly is incorrect and so our original assumption, that there are integer solutions to the below is incorrect.
$$A^3 + B^3 = C^3$$

Q.E.D. (Hopefully.)
Is this correct? I cannot find anything wrong with it unlike my previous one.
Thank you.

Comment: *'We know from earlier that this is either odd or even."* You can drop "from earlier" :)

Comment: You forgot about ODD+EVEN=ODD (and in fact the writing $(qA)^3 + (pA)^3 = (qC)^3$ can only be of that form).

Comment: You've already asked this question. and you accepted an answer to that same question. Do not re-post a question you've already posted.  Instead, edit the original.

Comment: @amWhy I think this is not a duplicate, because the proof attempt is quite different.

Comment: @amWhy This proof attempt seems very different from the other one; why shouldn't it deserve it's own question?

Comment: The observation made by @ArnaudMortier seems on point.  You begin the second half of the proof with "If we assume it [$qA$] is even, then..."  But you never follow up with "If, on the other hand, $qA$ is odd, then..."  You need to consider that case.